# Joomla workspace for students and teachers

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

Need to create in Joomla 3.2 an workspace where lecture should add delete edit data about courses or lecture notes. Student also should take information about lectures or trainings.
Any idea how to manage this? Is this any extension which allows easily performing this task?
Regards

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What does "where lecture should add delete edit data" mean? The entire purpose of Joomla is content management. Users can log in and edit content per your configuration.

Comment: Have a look on the Joomla Extensions Directoy. Personally, I wouldn't use Joomla for this. I remember there being a dedicated platform/system for this but can't remember the name of it.

Comment: It is not clear what are your requirements and if there is already another established system. Do you need to create an online training site ? @Lodder: Are you referring to platforms like moodle ?

Comment: @FFrewin - yes, that was the one I was thinking of :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Joomla! CMS for e-learning purposes, then you can take a look at JoomlaLMS. It is a fully functional Joomla centered learning management system with training / testing options, self-assessments and advanced conferencing applications.
[www.joomlalms.com](http://joomlalms.com/)